# Fabric JS loadSVGFromString include used defined custom attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I have an SVG string like this

`<svg ...> <image id="Lager_1" data-name="Lager 1" width="2" height="3" xlink:href="data:image/png;base..." y="0" x="0" x_rel="0" y_rel="0" width_rel="0.2" height_rel="0.2" obj_id="0f83a8ca168e" comp_id="2c46c64a13c0"/> ...`

I have added some extra attributes such as `x_rel`, `y_rel`, `obj_id`, and `comp_id`. However as soon as I try to load this SVG onto a canvas using FabricJS `loadSVGFromString` like this:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, (objects, options) => {
    objects.forEach(obj => {
      console.log(obj)
      canvas.add(obj)
    })
```

And later outputting the contents of the canvas like this
`console.log(canvas)`
or
`console.log(canvas.toObject())`

I see that my custom attributes have been lost and are no longer included, is there a solution for this?

Comment: An SVG is basically just xml string. You can parse it using DOMParser() to get the attributes you need. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the options variable you are passing in using the `groupSVGElements` function:

```js
...
var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
...
canvas.add(obj);
```